# $f,g$ 2 linearly independent weight 12 entire modular form give rise to isomorphism between $SL_2(Z)\backslash H$ and $CP_1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let $M_{12}$ be weight 12(integral weighted) entire modular form(i.e. holomorphic at cusps). So over $dim_C(M_{12})=2$. Now pick out any $f,g\in M_{12}$ linearly independent.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The book says $[f,g]:SL_2(Z)\backslash H\to CP_1$ is isomorphism where $H$ is the upper half plane union all cusps. Does the book mean identify $SL_2(Z)\backslash H$ not as an orbifold rather than simply a sphere without orbifold structure?(I could not see why this has to be biholomorphic if it is equipped with orbifold structure as there will be locally branched covering.) I can see this is obviously bijection but I do not see this as homeomorphism.

Ref. Zagier 1-2-3 Modular Forms pg 11 Cor 2.

Comment: I think Zagier is just being imprecise. On p. 9, he remarks that the two elliptic points become singularities on $\overline{\Gamma(1) \backslash \mathfrak{h}}$, and since $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is nonsingular this means they can't be isomorphic. What he probably actually means is that once we resolve these singularities, the resulting nonsingular Riemann surface is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$. One can resolve the singularities by defining specific charts that take into account these stabilizers: this is done for instance in $\S2.2$ of Diamond and Shurman or $\S1.8$ of Miyake.